# jQuery hover function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have a hover function that is supposed to move an arrow under the corrent the link that someone hovers over. The problem is, the arrow never returns to the current link when the person stops hovering over the link. However, if I set the left properly with a constant value it works. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the js:

```
$('#navbar li').hover(function(event) {
    var currentId = '#' + $('body').attr('id') + '_link';
    var xCordCurrent = $(currentId).offset().left - ($('#arrow').width() / 2);
    var xCordHover = $(event.target).offset().left + ($(event.target).width() / 2) - ($('#arrow').width() / 2);
        $('#arrow').animate(
        { left: xCordHover }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeOutBack'
        })  
    }, function(event) {
        $('#arrow').animate(
        { left: xCordCurrent }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeOutBack'
        })
    });
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="arrow"></div>
<ul id="navbar">
    <li id="home_link"><a href="/">home</a></li>
    <li id="portfolio_link"><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="resume_link"><a href="resume.php">resume</a></li>
    <li id="photos_link"><a href="photography.php">photos</a></li>
    <li id="blog_link"><a href="blog/">blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML/CSS? Also the JS here looks incomplete.

Comment: `xCordCurrent` doesn't seem to be defined in your out-handler

Answer (score -1):

The following complete example worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var current = $('#' + $('body').attr('id') + '_link');
                var oldLeft = current.position().left + (current.width() / 2) - (arrow.width() / 2);
                var arrow = $('#arrow').css('left', oldLeft);
                $('#navbar li').hover(function() {
                    var h = $(this);
                    var newLeft = h.position().left + (h.width() / 2) - (arrow.width() / 2);
                    arrow.stop().animate({ left: newLeft }, {
                        duration: 'slow',
                        //easing: 'easeOutBack'
                    });
                }, function() {
                    arrow.stop().animate({ left: oldLeft }, {
                        duration: 'slow',
                        //easing: 'easeOutBack'
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #navbar { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: auto; }
            #navbar li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; }
            #navbar li a { margin: 1em; }
            #arrow { background-color: #f00; height: 3px; width: 10px; left: 0; position: absolute; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="resume">
        <div id="arrow"></div>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li id="home_link"><a href="/">home</a></li>
            <li id="portfolio_link"><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="resume_link"><a href="resume.php">resume</a></li>
            <li id="photos_link"><a href="photography.php">photos</a></li>
            <li id="blog_link"><a href="blog/">blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice how your easing method of `easeOutBack` is commented out. As per the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing) the only valid easing methods are `linear` and `swing`. I hope this at least gives you some insight to your problem.